# What does "Cannot create closure on abstract inline method" mean?

Tags: haxe

I don't really get this.
I have a simple class with private map:

```
var mapping = new Map<String, Array<PushButton>>();
```

I declare a public function:

```
function addFlagMapping(flag:String, pushButton:PushButton):Void
{

}
```

But when I try to call a `mapping.set` method inside this function I get this error:
**Cannot create closure on abstract inline method**

What does it mean? I don't have any inline abstract methods at all!

Comment: A little more context would greatly help since nothing in that code is going to fail.

Comment: why does your mapping property is of type Array<PushButton> if then you set just a PushButton to the map? (or at least i'm guessing you are, from the little information we have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with enums.

It's only related to completion in try.haxe.org, (you were testing there right?) cause
- it compiles fine if you ignore the error
- the error doesn't pop in FlashDevelop.

Here is a working example
http://try.haxe.org/#9695e

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was FlashDevelop which threw this error while I was typing and it was very enoyying.